# How return a value from a custom tag

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags, taglib

If I calculate a value in my function `doTag` (or `doStartTag`), how I could store it in a variable for use in my view, inside the tag, like the parameter `varStatus` from tag `c:forEach` in the example below?

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${list}" varStatus="status">
    ${status.index} - ${item}
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store a variable inside your doTag in this way:

```
 public void doTag() throws JspException, IOException {  
        String status = "status test";
        getJspContext().setAttribute("status", status);  
        ...
    }
```

And then you could call it normally:

```
${status}
```

Something like that.